# error CS0138: A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Collision2D'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a script for moving platforms, where Player can stay "blocked" on it.But when i saved the script, it showed me this: `error CS0138: A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Collision2D' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead

The script is :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Collision2D;

public class OnMovingPlat : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 velocity;

    private bool moving;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.WasWithPlayer())
        {
            moving = true;
            collision.collider.transform.SetParent(transform);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.WasWithPlayer())
        {
            collision.collider.transform.SetParent(null);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (moving)
        {
            transform.position += (velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

What can i do ?

Comment: And? Remove `using UnityEngine.Collision2D;`

Comment: What do you think that error means?

Comment: And, shows me this : error CS1061: 'Collision2D' does not contain a definition for 'WasWithPlayer' and no accessible extension method 'WasWithPlayer' accepting a first argument of type 'Collision2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @RedMice `WasWithPlayer` is not part of the engine API. I suppose it should be an extension method. Is that method your code?

Comment: @ZorgoZ this code was not created by me entirely, i saw it on Youtube

Comment: Well, looks like you got incomplete code, missing some classes and methods in your code.

Comment: @RedMice Well, then look to find the rest of the code...

Comment: I solved, I replaced WasWithPlayer with gameObject.tag == "Player"

Answer (score 0):

Seams Collision2D becomes a Type. you may accidentally create a class name called "Collision2D" under "UnityEngine" namespace.